# How to adjust the dropdown levels in an rhandsontable

Tags: r, rhandsontable

I have the simple dataframe below:

```
DF2 = data.frame(agency_postcode = factor(rep(c(12345,45678,24124,32525,32325),2)),
                 car_group=factor(rep(c("Microcar","City car","Supermini","Compact","SUV"),2)),
                 transmission=factor(rep(c("automatic","manual"),5)))
```

and based on this I create an rhandsontable. The issue is that when I subset my dataframe I still get all the levels of the other columns in the dropdown while I would like to see only those related with the value I used to subset. In the example below I should have taken `'12345'` when displaying the dropdown and not all of the levels.

```
library(rhandsontable)

rhandsontable(DF2[ which(DF2$car_group=='Microcar'), ], rowHeaders = NULL, width = 550, height = 300)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that dropdown shows all the factors that exist so I re-factored based on my subset like:

```
newdata <- DF2[ which(DF2$car_group=='Microcar'), ]




for(i in 1:ncol(newdata)){
     newdata[,i] <- factor(newdata[,i])
   }
```